# Xcode Audio Bug

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have an app that was recently working 100% until I moved an audio file into a new group. Now AVPlayer is failing to initialize. I moved the audio file back and the bug persists. How can I begin to workaround this?

Edit: AVPlayer isn't failing to initialize, it just doesn't stream the audio... and the bug only exists in simulator. I Ad-hoc tested on my iPhone and it's working as expected

```
2017-05-28 08:00:00.995 appName[6714:472740] 08:00:00.960 WARNING:  40: ERROR: couldn't get default input device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2017-05-28 08:00:00.996 appName[6714:472740] 08:00:00.996 WARNING:  40: ERROR: couldn't get default output device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2017-05-28 08:00:00.996 appName[6714:472740] 08:00:00.996 ERROR:    708: Error finding valid input or output devices!
2017-05-28 08:00:00.997 appName[6714:472740] 08:00:00.997 ERROR:    312: error -66680
2017-05-28 08:00:00.997 appName[6714:472740] 08:00:00.997 ERROR:    130: * * * NULL AQIONode object
2017-05-28 08:00:00.997 appName[6714:472740] 08:00:00.997 ERROR:    753: Can't make UISound Renderer
2017-05-28 08:00:01.048 appName[6714:472434] 08:00:01.048 ERROR:    312: error -66680
2017-05-28 08:00:01.048 appName[6714:472434] 08:00:01.048 ERROR:    >aq> 1627: failed (-66680); will stop (11025/0 frames)
pause
```

Comment: I guess you have to test this on real devices than relying on Simulator. Was it working before in Simulator? If it was, try **Reset Content and Settings** in your Simulator.

Comment: yeah it was working in simulator fine before. I reset content and settings, and the audio played for 3 seconds before getting the same bug. I'm thinking project files are corrupt as I'm having several other issues with the project that seem to be file related as well